# Why does Zoom screenshare crash i3wm on annotating?

Tags: window-manager, i3-wm, zoom-meeting

I am on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS running [i3wm](https://i3wm.org).

```
~ [I] ➜ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
~ [I] ➜ i3 --version
i3 version 4.14.1 (2017-09-24) © 2009 Michael Stapelberg and contributors
```

I frequently use Zoom for meetings in the current pandemic situation and am able to use its screensharing facilities during meetings. However, as soon as someone (either a participant or I) attempts to **annotate** something on *my* screen that is being shared, the window manager crashes and blacks out. Then no one is able to see anything on my screen (including me). I can get a terminal using `Ctrl-Alt-FX` combination but have not able to get the window manager restarted. Usually I then have to restart my machine.

This problem **does not** happen if I am using the normal GNOME window manager (available as a choice when logging in). Has anyone else experienced this problem or can suggest a fix? I would really like to continue using i3wm when starting a Zoom meeting rather than having to log-out and in each time I need to attend a meeting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not on ubuntu (Enterprise Linux), but I was having issues with the annotations if I didn't have a compositor running.

I used [zoom's support article](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/202082128-Black-Screen-During-Screen-Sharing) to run with their recommended settings with `compton` instead of `xcompgr` and it seemed to fix the annotation issue.

Unfortunately I still have an issue where my screen sharing will randomly freeze. One problem at a time.

Comment: That works for my EXWM as well. The only drawback is that I don't see the annotation panel so I can't clear the annotations afterward. Still much better than a black screen